# Windows Phone 8 template in Visual Studio 2013 Preview

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am running Windows 8 x64 and have Visual Studio 2012 with the latest update and Visual Studio 2013 preview (latest update) installed. I also have the Windows Phone SDK for Windows Phone 8 development on Visual Studio 2012.

I have read somewhere online that there is no SDK required for Windows Phone 8 on Visual Studio 2013. But Where is the `new phone project` option?

[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Found it,
had to modify my vs2013 installation... (stupid me)
Is it an idea to leave this online for the community? (if I forget it again, and cannot find a source online lol!)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was it! It's really strange that the installer for Windows Phone SDK 8.0 says nothing about this at all.

Comment: and another strange thing is that i had vs2012 installed already with windows phone 8.0 sdk so i didn't tick this checkbox while installing vs2013, don't you think that it should have named differently?

Comment: Perhaps you did a full install?

Comment: I still can't see the option..!

Comment: This solved my problem. I installed and reinstalled the windows phone SDK like 3 times before, always performing a clean unninstall, before giving up. Thanks

Comment: no way to set the SDK without re-installing VS2013?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013 express edition and I dont see this option to choose the components to install

Answer (score 15):

For future references, I installed the Visual Studio 2013 **Professional** edition where the Windows Phone 8.0 SDK apparently wasn't included in the default installation. I browsed to the [Windows Phone Dev Center to download the SDK](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk) but this way doesn't integrate with Visual Studio 2013 as well - it surprisingly put Visual Studio 2012 Express edition on the PC...

**The only way to be able to incorperate the Windows Phone SDK is by modifying the installation of Visual Studio 2013**, just as the OP states.

Comment: then did you delete VS2013 and just use VS2012 for Windows Phone? Because I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177560/visual-studio-2013-and-windows-phone

Comment: No, VS2013 **can** use the Windows Phone SDK, but the SDK is by default not installed. You have to modify the installation to check the WP SDK and then click 'Update'. This will install the SDK for VS2013.

Comment: I look at VS 2013 ultimate with blend and there *no* option for windows phone at all in that above screen? What do I do to get that? Never Mind I am on windows 7!

Comment: wait wait wait.... Windows 8 is a prerequisite for Windows Phone 8 development? Presumably because of the emulator?

Comment: I can confirm that if you install on Windows 7, you won't see the option to install the Windows Phone 8 SDK. It requires Windows 8 or later, 64 bit .

Answer (score 2):

**If you are on Windows 7**, you won't see the option to install the Windows Phone 8 SDK. It requires Windows 8 or later, 64 bit.