# Windows Phone 8 apps using Visual studio 2013 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In a confusion of Upgrading  Visual studio 2010 to  2012/ 2013.

2013 is the only option for creating Windows store apps.But not giving a clear picture on the support for Windows Phone apps development.

My question is can i use VS2013 for the development of Windows Phone 8 apps?

Not so sure Windows 8.1 is available on phones as well or not in that case if i go for VS2013 can i create Windows Phone 8 app as well ?

Answer (score 10):

*This question is a duplicate of [Windows Phone 8 template in Visual Studio 2013 Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099572/windows-phone-8-template-in-visual-studio-2013-preview) but since I haven't got the reputation to post a comment, I'll combine JP Hellemons' answer and my own to answer this specific question.*

The [Windows Phone SDK 8.0](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk) **only** incorperates into Visual Studio 2012, even when Visual Studio 2013 is installed. To install the SDK for VS2012, we need to specify this during the initial installation of Visual Studio or do it afterwards by modifying the installation via `Control Panel → Add or remove programs`.

[image: Check the 'Windows Phone 8.0 SDK' when installing (or modifying the installation of) Visual Studio 2013]

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 (aka Metro) and Windows Phone are two distinct platforms. There's some speculation that the platforms will ultimately converge, but we are not there yet.

In order to start developing for Windows Phone you need to install the [Windows Phone SDK](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk). Unless you are using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate which supposedly ships with the WP SDK pre-installed.

Comment: Under the Windows 8 SDK download requirements , it says target machine need Visual Studio 2012 . So my question is can i  use the Windows Phone 8 SDK with visual studio 2013

Comment: I think the download instructions are simply outdated.