# Windows phone emulator doesn't run without Hyper V on Win 8.1....any alternative emulator?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Hi I am stuck with this problem above. Is there another way of testing windows phone apps in visual studio 12 without having to access hyper V? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a real device nearby? Because this would give you the best experience anyway.

Comment: No unfortunately not. I hope there is another solution than upgrading to 8.1 pro.....

Answer (score 8):

**If your hardware is not capable of running Hyper-V, you are dead in the water.**

Otherwise if your Windows 8.1 license does not include the support of Hyper V, you can check out the following post from Nokia where they install a Windows 8 x64 with an evaluation license on a virtual machine - or you could use a dedicated hardware setup or dual-boot etc.

Source: [Windows Phone 8 SDK on a Virtual Machine with Working Emulator](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Windows_Phone_8_SDK_on_a_Virtual_Machine_with_Working_Emulator)

---

### How to run WP Emulator without Hyper V? (summary of [nokia.com](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Windows_Phone_8_SDK_on_a_Virtual_Machine_with_Working_Emulator))

#### Hardware requirements

- 64bit host operating system;
- At least 8GB of RAM for the host machine;
- 30-40GB of free space.

#### Step-by-step

- Check if your computer is capable of running Windows 8 with Hyper-V

  - Download [Coreinfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722)
  - Open Command Prompt as administrator and execute `coreinfo.exe –v` (in the folder where coreinfo.exe is located)
  - If you have SLAT enabled, it is marked by an asterisk `*` like `EPT * Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)`. If not, you are unable to run it hardware-wise.
- [Download Windows 8 **64bit** Developer Evaluation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx). Register with your Windows Live ID for a key of 90 days.
- Register on [vmware.com](http://www.vmware.com/). After registering, download a trial of VMWare Workstation 9 or higher. This will grant you a 30 days license.

  - For extended usage, [download the free VMWare Playe](https://my.vmware.com/cn/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/5_0%7CPLAYER-503%7Cproduct_downloads)r.
- [Download the Windows Phone 8 SDK](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk). You can do this after installing the VM so that you can download the tool from within it.

#### Setting up the VM

Besides the trivial, straight-forward proces of creating a Virtual Machine, there are **two additional steps** that have to be done **to run Hyper-V**.

1. Before finishing the Virtual Machine configuration, click the 'Customize hardware' button.
   [image: VM Wizard - One click away from finish, but actually click 'Customize hardware']

   Go to the `Processors` section and enable `Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI`.
   [image: Enable the <code>Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI</code>]

   Finish the configuration and proceed to the next step.
2. Exit VMWare and open up the Virtual Machine configuration before installing Hyper-V. The config file is located in the folder where you created your Virtual Machine with the extension `.VMX`, e.g.: `Windows 8 x64.vmx`.

   Edit the file and add the text marked in red (hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE").
   [image: hypervisor.cpuid.v0 to "FALSE"]

---

If you are using Visual Studio 2013 you might want to check out these posts as well when installing the Windows Phone SDK.

- [Windows Phone 8 template in Visual Studio 2013 Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099572/windows-phone-8-template-in-visual-studio-2013-preview)
- [Windows Phone 8 apps using Visual studio 2013 Professional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585638/windows-phone-8-apps-using-visual-studio-2013-professional?lq=1)

Comment: thanks for that...how do I open the .vmx file though? and where do I need to install hyper v after that? little confused...thanks

Comment: i figured out the vmx file...this error shows up when startin gthe vm.

Comment: Please check the source for more information. This is _just_ a summary.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.nokia.com/resources/remote-device-access
Remote access to real device which you can use to test your app.
I have no personal experience from it, so I can't say how suitable it is to replace local emulator or real device, but it might be worth checking out.

Comment: Note: the above mentioned site is now deactivated.