# Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Phone 8 device - Will it work

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I've started a new Windows Phone 8.1 project in Visual Studio 2013 and I've been doing a lot of coding already.

My questions is, can I run this project on a Windows Phone 8 device?
Wikipedia (for example) says it isn't possible, that's why I wanted a second opinion.

If I do have to start over, will I have a lot of trouble importing all my previous files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously your project needs to target 8.0 to run on 8.0 or higher.

Start a new 8.0 project and import all your code. If you don't have any 8.1 specific code (which is likely), it will compile fine and run on 8.0 and 8.1.

Comment: An easy accepted answer for you I guess. Well, you were most descriptive so there you have it :)
Thanks everyone!

Comment: an answer is an answer :)

Comment: I am still wondere, I have WP 8.0 SDK installed on my VS 2013 RC2, but I can't seem to choose what target I want my project to be for. It always targets WP 8.1, any ideas?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585638/windows-phone-8-apps-using-visual-studio-2013-professional

Comment: thumbmunkeys: Nope, I already have WP 8.0 SDK installed, that's not the problem. I recently installed 8.1 SDK and since then, all project for WP I create target WP 8.1 without any indication to where I can change the target back to 8.0.

Comment: did you modify your VS2013 installation as shown in the link?

Comment: Yes I did. And afterwards I downloaded the 8.1 SDK from Microsoft's site and installed it. If I run the Visual Studio installer again and modify, I can still see WP 8.0 SDK checked.

Comment: I think I just found my answer in Step 5 of this tutorial:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263114.aspx Seems like I have to use VS2012 :/

Comment: I dont think so, the tutorial is not about the phone, but the PC OS. If you do find a solution, I'd be interested to hear about it.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately if you started the project in WP8.1, only devices with WP8.1 or above will be able to run your app.  If you want your app to run on WP8.0 you need to create an App that targets WP8.0 devices.
Good luck

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible. Same problem as with WP7 and WP8, you can run WP7 apps on WP8 devices but not WP8 apps on WP7 devices.

Maybe you could create a WP8 project if your code doesn't use WP8.1 dependent stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to get the 8.1 update. If it hasn't been released to your phone yet, install the "Preview for Developers" App from [dev.windowsphone.com](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=330426&clcid=0x409). Then you'll be able to test your windows 8.1 app as well as universal apps.

Comment: Hi and thanks. (un)fortunately I don't own a Windows Phone nor do I intent to. I do everything on the emulator

Comment: In that case, you can get a windows phone 8.1 emulator in Visual Studio 2013 update 2, which at the time of this comment is a release candidate. All windows phone 8 devices will (should) eventually get the 8.1 update.