# Modifying visual studio's installation

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I can't find `windows phone 8` development tools in `visual studio 2013`. May be reason is same as mentioned here [Windows Phone 8 template in Visual Studio 2013 Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099572/windows-phone-8-template-in-visual-studio-2013-preview/18099625#18099625). What I want to know is how to modify visual studio's installation and include windows phone 8 dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check "Installing optional Components" section in this URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983433(v=vs.90).aspx