# Visual Studio 2013 and Windows Phone

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, visual-studio-2013

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 Pro and then I wanted to install Windows Phone 8 SDK. But it installed Express Edition of VS 2012. Now if I delete VS 2013, what happens with my VS 2012? Can I delete it, because I don't have enough memory for it? Can you help me, please!

Comment: Please accept one of the answers as the 'correct' answer of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can install this version of Visual Studio on a computer that already has an earlier version installed.

but

> If you uninstall a version of Visual Studio on a computer that has more than one version installed, the file associations for Visual Studio are removed for all versions.

More information : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx

Answer (score 1):

They are independent, you can uninstal one without influencing the other.