# Build windows phone 8 app using visual studio 2013

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I have x64 windows 8.1 pro, but the system doesn't support SLAT. So this means that I can develop WP8 apps, but I have to test app on physical devices. I have installed visual studio 2013 Update 2, but on opening new project to develop WP8 apps, options are coming to develop only WP8.1 apps. So, where is the SDK for WP8 as I had checked WP8 sdk during installation.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099572/windows-phone-8-template-in-visual-studio-2013-preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen such questions here, but its not the exact duplicate....i have already checked the windows phone sdk 8.0 during installation..its installed. I was wrong in project template selection at some points.
1) Blank app template for WP8 is not included in VS2013, however there is a workaround [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/windows-phone-8-blank-project) for c# projects

2) I was searching for javascript templates for WP8 app development, but its for WP8.1 only, phonegap may be a solution.

3) WP8 sdk is there, we have to look for right supported templates, like App building using Silverlight, HTML5, in C#, visual basic and C++ sections.

So the main point is I was looking in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can find SDK 8.0 for develop WP8 application Here.   https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

U can download Sdk 8.0 from here and can use to develop your Apps.