# No JavaScript Intellisense in Visual Studio Express 2012 For Windows Phone

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, visual-studio-express, javascript-intellisense

I'm developing mobile app for windows phone using Windows phone 8 SDK (Visual Studio Express 2012 For Windows Phone). I want to use autoComplete facilities when coding in Javascript. For that I need to use Intellisense for JS.

According to my knowledge, To configure Intellisense according to my knowledge,It have navigate to the [Tools] > [Options] > Text Editor > JavaScript > IntelliSense >

But in my 
*[Tools] > [Options] > Text Editor >* list there is No item called  JavaScript.

Please someone help me for solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running Visual Studio 12, or Visual Studio 2012?  You state "12" in the text, but have tagged the post with "visual-studio-2012".  Confusingly, version "12" is the 2013 release.

Regardless, please ensure you are running Visual Studio 2013 with at least update 2 (preferably update 4), and also be sure to enabled the "Web Developer Tools" features.

See [Windows Phone 8 template in Visual Studio 2013 Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099572/windows-phone-8-template-in-visual-studio-2013-preview) for a similar issue to see if any of this applies.

Comment: VS2012 supported building Windows Phone 8 apps with C#, VB, or C++ (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402571(v=vs.105).aspx ).  To build Windows Phone apps with JavaScript/HTML, I believe you will need VS2013 and to target Win Phone 8.1 (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/08/building-windows-phone-8-1-apps-in-html.aspx )