# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate no Windows Phone 8 template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone

I don't see the `Windows Phone 8` template in `VS 2013 Ultimate` edition. Yes, I have already tried solution [from this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099572/windows-phone-8-template-in-visual-studio-2013-preview) but it doesn't work, or maybe this solution was just for `VS 2013 Preview.`

Any suggestion and workaround is appreciated

I have VS updated to latest 4 update.

[image]

Comment: Have you updated to the latest version of VS2013.  I know that this template wasn't in the original, but was added in either update 2 or 3.

Comment: Yes, I have update 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight. That is the only way to create WP 8.0 app. There is also WP 8.1 Silverlight but it is recommended not to go Silverlight because all the apps are going in the *Universal App* direction.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Phone 8 you will need to download and install SDK from [this](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk). Would recommend you to try to download windows 8.1 sdk. Moreover refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319443/no-template-for-windows-phone-8-1-in-visual-studio-express-2013-with-update-2-rc/23444923#23444923)  to find the new location of windows phone templates

Comment: I have 8.1 SDK, which is by default AFAIK, but I want template for 8-th, not 8.1. The stackoverflow question is asking for 8.1 template, which I have already found.

Comment: Then I believe you need to download the windows 8 sdk from the link that I provided then only you would get the 8 emulator options

Comment: I downloaded 8 SDK but according to this setup http://s28.postimg.org/ti0bpuoxp/Screenshot_2.png it is installing VS 2012 :(

Comment: Windows Phone SDK 8.0 Update 3 Emulators or Windows Phone SDK 8.0 Update for Windows Phone.. dont know which one I had selected but after installing then I had Windows 8 emulators integrated. Though it was other way round had my IDE uploaded when 8 emulators came out then updated to 8.1 when they got released but still it should work in your case. just select the latest update of windows 8 and try.